# Force prefix in all fields of XML tags for the input Spring WS SOAP, Using Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm using Spring SOAP and it auto generates a WSDL for my SOAP web service.

My problem is that I have this input generated by SOAP UI when I use my WSDL:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.servicename.test/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ser:serviceName>
        <InputParameters>
            <service>
                <id>0</id>
            </service>
        </InputParameters>
    </ser:serviceName>
</soapenv:Body>
```

But I need something like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.servicename.test/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ser:serviceName>
        <ser:InputParameters>
            <ser:service>
                <ser:id>0</ser:id>
            </ser:service>
        </ser:InputParameters>
    </ser:serviceName>
</soapenv:Body>
```

How can I add the prefix "ser:" to all my tags?

Comment: How did you generate the WSDL? Did you create request and response schemas (.xsd)?

Comment: I use annotations in my Java classes like @XmlElement(name = "service", nillable = true)... and so on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501907/adding-namespace-prefix-xml-string-using-xml-dom.

Hope this link helps you out.