# Loop through all elements in XML using NodeList

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I want to loop through all elements in a piece of XML printing each one.  My problem is that I keep getting a null pointer exception after the `staff1` tag, i.e. `john 465456433 gmail1 area1 city1`

This my Java code to print all elements in an xml file:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

System.out.println("----------------------------");

Node n=null;
Element eElement=null;

for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {           
  System.out.println(nList.getLength());     
  n= nList.item(i);                            
  System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + n.getNodeName());


  if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    eElement = (Element) n.getChildNodes();
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + n.getNodeName());
    name = eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(i).getTextContent(); //here throws null pointer exception after printing staff1 tag
    phone = eElement.getElementsByTagName("phone").item(i).getTextContent();
    email = eElement.getElementsByTagName("email").item(i).getTextContent();
    area = eElement.getElementsByTagName("area").item(i).getTextContent();
    city = eElement.getElementsByTagName("city").item(i).getTextContent();
  }
  n.getNextSibling();
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
  <staff1>
    <name>john</name>
    <phone>465456433</phone>
    <email>gmail1</email>
    <area>area1</area>
    <city>city1</city>
  </staff1>
  <staff2>
    <name>mary</name>
    <phone>4655556433</phone>
    <email>gmail2</email>
    <area>area2</area>
    <city>city2</city>
  </staff2>
  <staff3>
    <name>furvi</name>
    <phone>4655433</phone>
    <email>gmail3</email>
    <area>area3</area>
    <city>city3</city>
  </staff3>
</company>
```

Expected Output:

```
john
465456433
gmail1
area1
city1
mary
4655556433
gmail2
area2
city2
furvi
4655433
gmail3
area3
city3
```

Comment: What is the actual output you got?

Comment: At what line it throws NullPointerException?

Comment: For wild cards you need XPath.

Comment: after getting staff1 tag i mean (john 465456433 gmail1 area1 city1) it throws null pointer exception on name field

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse("file.xml");
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList nl = docEle.getChildNodes();
    int length = nl.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element el = (Element) nl.item(i);
            if (el.getNodeName().contains("staff")) {
                String name = el.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
                String phone = el.getElementsByTagName("phone").item(0).getTextContent();
                String email = el.getElementsByTagName("email").item(0).getTextContent();
                String area = el.getElementsByTagName("area").item(0).getTextContent();
                String city = el.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getTextContent();
            }
        }
    }
```

Iterate over all children and `nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE` is used to filter text nodes out. If there is nothing else in XML what remains are staff nodes.

For each node under stuff (name, phone, email, area, city)

```
 el.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
```

`el.getElementsByTagName("name")` will extract the "name" nodes under stuff,
`.item(0)` will get you the first node
and `.getTextContent()` will get the text content inside.

**Edit:** 
Since we have jackson I would do this in a different way. Define a pojo for the object:

```
public class Staff {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String area;
    private String city;
...getters setters
}
```

Then using jackson:

```
    JsonNode root = new XmlMapper().readTree(xml.getBytes());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    root.forEach(node -> consume(node, mapper));



private void consume(JsonNode node, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    try {
        Staff staff = mapper.treeToValue(node, Staff.class);
        //TODO your job with staff
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks could you make the first part of your code for all elements

Comment: `nl.getLength() > 0` is not required as it will not enter the loop anyways.

Comment: Note that getLength on a NodeList is, depending on the implementation, potentially very slow. See https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/feature-requests/317/ for example. It's best to store the length in a variable before iterating over the NodeList.

Answer (score 8):

```
public class XMLParser {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      try {
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("xml input"));
         NodeList nl=doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

         for(int k=0;k<nl.getLength();k++){
             printTags((Node)nl.item(k));
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {/*err handling*/}
   }

   public static void printTags(Node nodes){
       if(nodes.hasChildNodes()  || nodes.getNodeType()!=3){
           System.out.println(nodes.getNodeName()+" : "+nodes.getTextContent());
           NodeList nl=nodes.getChildNodes();
           for(int j=0;j<nl.getLength();j++)printTags(nl.item(j));
       }
   }
}
```

Recursively loop through and print out all the xml child tags in the document, in case you don't have to change the code to handle dynamic changes in xml, provided it's a well formed xml.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to loop through XML elements using JDOM.

```
        List<Element> nodeNodes = inputNode.getChildren();
        if (nodeNodes != null) {
            for (Element nodeNode : nodeNodes) {
                List<Element> elements = nodeNode.getChildren(elementName);
                if (elements != null) {
                    elements.size();
                    nodeNodes.removeAll(elements);
                }
            }
```

Comment: That is way too easy.  XML is meant to be hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeList listaHijos = docEle.getChildNodes();
        listaHijos = listaHijos.item(2).getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < listaHijos.getLength(); i++) {
            eElement = (Element) listaHijos.item(i);
            n2 = eElement.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < n2.getLength(); j++) {
                System.out.println("elem:" + n2.item(j).getNodeName() + " :" + n2.item(j).getTextContent() + "j" + j);
                if (n2.item(j).getNodeName().equals("detallesAdicionales")) {                                                                        
                    eElement = (Element) n2.item(j);
                    n6 = eElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("todo: " + n6.item(0).getAttributes().item(0) + n6.item(0).getAttributes().item(1));                        
                    System.out.println("todo2: " + n6.item(1).getAttributes().item(0) + n6.item(1).getAttributes().item(1));                        
                    System.out.println("todo3: " + n6.item(2).getAttributes().item(0) + n6.item(2).getAttributes().item(1));                        
                    System.out.println("nombre: " + n6.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("valor: " + n6.item(0).getAttributes().item(1).getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).