# Java XML Parsing into object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

We have a requirement of parsing xml data in java.
The xml data looks like this:

[xml_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFyh4.png)

1> The first question here is how to parse such data.I have tried the code suggested in this link :
[xmlparse with Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566596/loop-through-all-elements-in-xml-using-nodelist)
and have partial success. The only doubt here is how can i can to reach "" tag.

2>The second question is if the data is parsed how can we can store the values in single object,so that we can get length and values of "CRAWL", "Test", "Check"(Tables) separately(from single object)?

Please help me as how can we achieve this?

Abhi

Comment: If you have a schema (xsd) for your xml format, it would be trivial to parse and transform them into classes via xjc / JAXB. A schema can be created automatically from test data for many cases, search online for a generator.
For JAXB, see for example http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/12/jaxb-tutorial-xml-binding.html

Comment: It is all right to refer to data outside of stack-overflow, but the question written here should be specific and complete enough to convince those who can help you to open your link.