# How to Read XML Response using Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am calling a web service and get the response as XML. Here is XML response,

```
<Response>
    <NO>1</NO>
    <NAME>John Doe</NAME>
</Response>
<Response>
    <NO>2</NO>
    <NAME>Jane Doe</NAME>
</Response>
```

I am trying to get each data from each response. I need to get each value.

Here is my Java code,

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder()
                    .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response.toString())));

            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Response");
            System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) node;

                    NodeList id = (NodeList) element.getElementsByTagName("Response");
                    System.out.println(id);
                    NodeList nodeLists = element.getChildNodes();

                    for (int j = 0; j < nodeLists.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node n = nodeLists.item(j);

                        if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element name = (Element) n;
                            System.out.println(name.getAttributes().getNamedItem("NO").getNodeValue());
                            System.out.println(name.getAttributes().getNamedItem("NAME").getNodeValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I can't get What I need. Nothing prints.

I need to print each value like this,

```
1
John Doe
2
Jane Doe
```

Basically, it needs to iterate over all `<Response>` Tags and give me the available data. But my code doesn't work.

So anybody can help me? Greatly appreciate that.

Comment: Have you tried using JAXB?

Comment: @daniu Not yet. But I will try. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never work on XML parsing but when I debug your Code in my machine I got an error something like,

```
[Fatal Error] :1:84: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 84; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at com.flotomate.fd.system.etc.OprUtility.main(OprUtility.java:87)
```

and search on StackOverflow what cause I got an error I find this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566596/loop-through-all-elements-in-xml-using-nodelist)

> issue is not root element Added.

after I add root element still not fix. so I follow pattern same as [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566596/loop-through-all-elements-in-xml-using-nodelist)

not Sure optimize and well define but working

```
String response = " <root>"
                      +"   <Response>  "
                      + "       <NO>1</NO>  "
                      + "       <NAME>John Doe</NAME>  " 
                      + "   </Response>  " 
                      + "   <Response>  "
                      + "       <NO>2</NO>  " 
                      + "       <NAME>Jane Doe</NAME>  " 
                      + "  </Response>  "
                      + "</root>";
    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(
            new InputSource(new StringReader(response.toString())));

    NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        if (element.getNodeName().contains("Response")) {
            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("NO").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("NAME").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
    }
}

    //And from this also.....
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element1 = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("NO").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("NAME").item(0).getTextContent());
    }
```

output:

```
1
John Doe
2
Jane Doe
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
NodeList id = (NodeList) element.getElementsByTagName("Response");
```

This will give you a nodelist of all elements with tagname **Response**. But you are not using this node list in your below code. Rather you are iterating on `element.getChildNodes()`. You should iterate on the `id`, or more specifically `id` is your required nodelist.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Thanks for your answer.