# Adding Namespace to Java (Apache FOP's - JSP) file parsing through a XSL stylesheet

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to use Apache FOP to create PDF documents for an application that I am working on.

This needs me to create a valid XSL-FO file which the FOP engine then parses to format the styling of documents that it creates.

The XSL file has custom namespaces that makes the FOP engine throw an error when it tries through parse through the files. The error I get goes,

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.checkDOMNSErr(CoreDocumentImpl.java:2526)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrNSImpl.setName(AttrNSImpl.java:113)
    ....
```

Example of namespaces in XSL/XML file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:altova="http://www.altova">

<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
```

FOP JSP file code that parses through the XSL:

```
<%@ page import='java.io.*'%>
<%@ page import='org.xml.sax.InputSource'%>
<%@ page import='org.apache.fop.apps.Driver'%>
<%@ page import='org.apache.fop.apps.Options'%>
<%@ page import='oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument'%>
<%@ page import='oracle.xml.parser.v2.XSLProcessor'%>
<%@ page import='oracle.xml.parser.v2.XSLStylesheet'%>
<%@ page import='oracle.xml.parser.v2.DOMParser'%>
<%
response.setContentType("application/pdf");

XMLDocument   v_doc;
XSLStylesheet v_xsl = null;
String        v_fop;
DOMParser     parser = new DOMParser();
XSLProcessor processor = new XSLProcessor();
// set the encoding for the XML Processing
String        v_encode = "UTF-8";

// get the XSL
v_xsl = new XSLStylesheet(new    java.io.StringReader(request.getParameter("template")),null);

// get the XML String from the form which was posted
parser.parse(new java.io.StringReader(request.getParameter("xml")));
// get the XML Document
v_doc = parser.getDocument();

// create an output stream to get the transformed results
ByteArrayOutputStream v_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// transform the xml and xsl to get an FOP
processor.processXSL(v_xsl, v_doc, v_out);
// convert the FOP byte array to a string with encoding set above
v_fop = new String(v_out.toByteArray(),v_encode);

//
// Now call the apache FOP processing
//
Driver driver = new Driver();
// set the desired output
// see http://xml.apache.org/fop/output.html for all output types
driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF);

// set the input for the FOP engine
driver.setInputSource(new InputSource(new StringReader(v_fop)));
// set the output to stream to the browser
driver.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
// process
driver.run();
%>
```

Now,
    [Adding namespace to an already created XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133754/adding-namespace-to-an-already-created-xml-document)
speaks about something on the same lines where I need to add code similar to .setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:ns2", "http://"); to my JSP for it to understand XML namespaces and to overcome the NAMESPACE_ERR error.

I am not a Java guy and would appreciate any help with regards to the code that I need to be working with.

Thanks,
Mitt.

Answer (score 0):

Use the top level element of the stylesheet to define all the namespaces:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:altova="http://www.altova" xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
```

Then remove the inline namespaces:

```
<x:xmpmeta>
<rdf:RDF>
```

**References**

- [W3C DOM: Namespaces Algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/namespaces-algorithms.html)