# XML Signature Reference digest uses parent namespace

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-namespaces, sha256

I need to sign an XML-File in Java, which needs to contain 3 `Reference`s.
While 2 of them are valid (expected digest == actual digest), one is invalid.
The relevant part of the XML Looks like:

```
<QualifyingProperties xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="Signature1">
    <SignedProperties Id="SignedProperties_1">
        <SignedSignatureProperties>
            <SigningTime>2014-11-27T13:49:36</SigningTime>
        </SignedSignatureProperties>
    </SignedProperties>
</QualifyingProperties>
```

The `Reference` only references the `Element` "SignedProperties" and its children.
As you can see the "QualifyingProperties" `Element` defines a namespace (`xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"`) and i guess thats the problem:

After having a look at the log i found, that the "Pre-Digest" Value looks like:

```
<SignedProperties xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="SignedProperties_1">
    <SignedSignatureProperties>
        <SigningTime>2014-11-27T13:49:36</SigningTime>
    </SignedSignatureProperties>
</SignedProperties>
```

While the "SignedProperties" `Element` in the real file does not contain the namespace, but its parent does.
I found out, that the actual digest matches the SHA-256 of the "Pre-Digest" value, while the expected digest matches the SHA-256 of the real file (without the namespace).

The `Reference` is created with the following code:

```
Reference sigPropRef = fac.newReference("#SignedProperties_1", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null),
    Collections.singletonList(sigPropTransform), "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties", "reference-signedpropeties"
);
```

Where the `sigPropTransform` is a `CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE` `Transform`.

My question is, how can i solve the problem, i.e. how can i prevent the namespace to be added to the "SignedProperties" `Element`, before calculating the digest?

If you need any other informations please leave a comment, i am pretty new to this theme, so i am not sure which informations are relevant and which not.
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** After playing arround a bit, it seems to me, that the "actual digest" is the digest, the validator calculated, while the "expected digest" is the digest inside the "DigestValue" `Element`.
That means, that the digest value inside my file matches the SHA-256 of the referenced filepart, but the validator for some reason calculates the digest WITh the parents namespace.
So i guess what i need is to include the parents namespace in my digest calculation.

**EDIT:** I continued playing arround and now i have not only the Pre-Digest value of the validator but also the one of my "digest calculation".
That one gives me:

```
<SignedProperties Id="SignedProperties_1"><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningTime>2014-11-27T15:51:26</SigningTime></SignedSignatureProperties></SignedProperties>
```

when i give it the following `Transform`:

```
Transform sigPropTransform = fac.newTransform(CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE, (ExcC14NParameterSpec)null);
```

And:

```
<SignedProperties xmlns:ds="some-url" xmlns:msg="some-other-url" Id="SignedProperties_1"><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningTime>2014-11-27T15:52:49</SigningTime></SignedSignatureProperties></SignedProperties>
```

when i don't give it any `Transform`.
The namespace `xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"` is never included.

How do i include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more tries i finally found the actuall problem, as well as the solution:
As i allready stated in the question, the digest calculation did not use the parents namespace, defined as `xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"`.
This was, because i did never "register" it as a namespace, but i only added it as a normal `Attribute`.
To "register" the namespace i need to call `setAttributeNS` instead of `setAttribute`.
The code then looks something like:

```
Element eQualifyingProperties= doc.createElement("QualifyingProperties");
eQualifyingProperties.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");
```

The first parameter is the namespace-uri of the `Attribute` and since the `Attribute` is a namespace it is the URI of the XML-Namespaces.
The second parameter is the attribute-name, since it should not have any praefix it is simply "xmlns".
The third parameter is the actual attibute-value, which is the namespace-uri i want to "register".
The `Element eQualifyingProperties` is the parent of the "SignedProperties" `Element`.

After registering the namespace as a real namespace (not as an attribute), the defined `Transform`

```
Transform sigPropTransform = fac.newTransform(CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE, (ExcC14NParameterSpec)null);
```

includes it in the digest calculation.

I found this solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146971/3182091) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you cannot prevent adding a namespace - it's being add during canonicalizaton.
[This](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/xmldsig.html) one helped me when i had identical issue ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Did you allready read my "EDIT"? I allready found out, that the namespace is added automatically during canonicalization, so now it seems like i need to add it to my digest calculation. The parents namespace is a "no-praefix" namespace. How do i tell the Canonicalization, that it should use it to calculate the digest?

Comment: "calculate digest" to create sinature, or to validate signature? Because if you're doing signature by yourself, you can calculate digest from e.g. <Signed Properties> in exactly the same way as validator is doing this

Comment: I am not doing it myself, i am using `Reference` for that. I need to give it the rigth `Transform`s, so that it includes the "no-name" namespace. If i don't give it any `Transform`s it includes all the namespaces, defined in the whole document, except the one without praefix (the one it should include). If i use `Exclusive Cannonicalization` it does not include any namespace. I will update the question!

Comment: Found the solution (see my answer). The problem was, that the namespace was not registered as a namespace, but only as a regular attribute. Thanks for pointing me in the rigth direction. +1